# Let $f$ be continuously differentiable function on $[a,b]$ then which of the following is true

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f$ be continuously differentiable function on $[a,b]$. If $f(a) = f(b)$ and 
>    $f'(a) = f'(b)$, then there exist points $x_1$ and $x _2$ in $(a,b)$ such that $x_1 \ne x_2$  , and $f'(x_1) = f'(x_2)$.

I need to prove/disprove the above claim.

I have tried to solve this By using Lagrange Mean Value theorem, Rolle's theorem But I am unable to prove this result.

Any hints on how should I attack this problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may apply the following statement to $g =f'$.

> **Proposition.** Suppose that $g : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that $g(a) = g(b)$. Then there exist $x_1, x_2 \in (a, b)$ such that $x_1 \neq x_2$ but $g(x_1) = g(x_2)$.

*Hint for the proof.* If $g$ is constant, there is nothing to prove.

Otherwise, we can find $c \in (a, b)$ such that $g(c) \neq g(a)$. Now pick any value $y_0$ strictly between $g(c)$ and $g(a)$ and apply the intermediate value theorem to $y_0$ on $[a, c]$ and on $[c, b]$.

$\hspace{7.5em}$[image: Intuition]

Comment: Thank you !  Very nice proof. It uses only elementary properties of continuous function.